# How to update OPA policies on the fly

Tags: spring-security, authorization, microservices, open-policy-agent

I'm new to OPA (open policy agent) and trying to use OPA as centralized service for authorization.

I've couple of micro services built using Spring boot and I don't want to use spring security to guard my resources/controllers as this would require annotating my controllers with Spring security annotations and any change to resource and role mapping would result in deployment of services, that is motivation of using OPA, since my resource and role mapping and are saved in DB  (JSON format) and can be configured/changed on the fly, so how do I update the OPA policies, I came across the bundles API but that requires the policies (rego files) to be packed as tar file and OPA will pull it on regular interval, so how do I translate my JSON (resource to role mappings) to rego files?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need to. Bundles may contain both .rego files as well as .json files for data, so what you'd likely want to do is to fetch the JSON data from your datasource when building your bundle and publish that on updates, or just at some fixed interval. See the docs on the [bundle file format](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/management/#bundle-file-format) for further details.